# Как посчитать количество произведенных сравнений элементов массива в PascalABC?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

"Программа для поиска заданного элемента в массиве"

Суть:
Заданный элемент для поиска вводить с клавиатуры.
Массив заполнять с клавиатуры.

В результате выполнения программы вывести на экран:

1. Исходный массив,
2. Индекс заданного для поиска элемента или сообщение о том, что заданный элемент в массиве отсутствует.
3. **Сосчитать количество произведенных сравнений элементов массива с образцом, прежде чем будет найден искомый элемент и вывести полученное значение на экран.**

   ```
     const n = 10;
     var s, k: array [1..n] of integer;
         y, i, number, sravn: integer;
     begin
     writeln('Введите число ,которое будем искать в массиве');
     readln(number);

     writeln('Заполните ', n, ' элементов массива:');
     for i := 1 to n do
     begin
       readln(s[i]);
       if number = s[i] then
       begin
         y := y + 1;
         k[y] := i;
       end;
     end;

     writeln('Массив:',s);
     if y = 0 then writeln('В массиве нет такого числа!') else
     if y = 1 then writeln('Число найдено, его порядковый номер = ', k[y]) else
     begin
     write('Число найдено, его порядковые номера = ');
     for i := 1 to y do
     write(k[i], ' ');
     end;
     end.
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если число найдено, то количество сравнений равно его индексу в массиве, а если нет - то количеству элементов в массиве. Все индексы никто запоминать вроде не просил.

```
for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    readln(s[i]);
    if number = s[i] then
    begin
      writeln('Число найдено, его индекс и количество сравнений ', i);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
writeln('Число не найдено, количество сравнений', n) 
end.
```